# Change image as user scrolls up and down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I have two images (a closed box and an open box) very similar to the animation under the banner on this [site](https://supamama.co.za/). The image changes when the user scrolls up and down the page. How would I create this effect?

I have tried to use Jquery mousewheel but that is not working for me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[Open box image](https://supamama.co.za/img/product/open.png).

[Closed box image](https://supamama.co.za/img/product/closed.png).

Comment: what  is the html and js code have you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a sample of code you could study to learn:

```js
     var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 1;
     $("div").scroll(function(){

         var nowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
 //    console.log(nowScrollTop);
         if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - nowScrollTop) >= delta){
            if (nowScrollTop > lastScrollTop){
                // SCROLLING DOWN 
        $('#image img').attr('src', "https://supamama.co.za/img/product/closed.png");
            } else {
                // SCROLLING UP 
        $('#image img').attr('src', "https://supamama.co.za/img/product/open.png");
            }
         lastScrollTop = nowScrollTop;
         }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div style="border:1px solid black;width:470px;height:550px;overflow:scroll;">
<div>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>
<div>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>
   <div id="image" >
      <img src = "https://supamama.co.za/img/product/open.png" height = "250" width = "370"  />
<div>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>
<div>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>
      </div>
  </div>
   </body>
```